# In Perl: How to give the filename to be opened dynamically

Tags: perl, file

I want to open a file whose name should be given as string to the open() function in Perl.How can it be achieved.

I have the following code shown below, which shows some errors in second open statement

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $globalpath = "/lhome/tirumala2/cvadlapu_view2/3rdparty/embedded/bsa_examples/linux/";
my $line;
open (TEXT_FILE, "/lhome/tirumala2/DDT_expect_module/test_strings.txt"); 

while ($line = <TEXT_FILE>) 
{
   print "$line";
   open ( APP_FILE, "/lhome/tirumala2/cvadlapu_view2/3rdparty/embedded/bsa_examples/linux/$line/source/$line.c") or die "Cant open application file";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fisrt of all always use [three argument open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).
2. You are not using `$globalpath` variable in the shown code.
3. It might be possible to have some data along with `newline character` in `$line` variable. So try to chomp it first and see, it should work.

Try something like:

```
while ($line = <TEXT_FILE>)  { 
chomp $line;   # need to chomp the $line
print "$line";    
open ( my $app_file, "<" , "/lhome/tirumala2/cvadlapu_view2/3rdparty/embedded/bsa_examples/linux/$line/source/$line.c") or die "Cant open application file: $!";  
}
```